# Ionic v1 Cordova "prefs:root=" non-public URL scheme ios app rejection

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

My app for iOS got rejected with the following error:

Guideline 2.5.1 - Performance - Software Requirements
Your app uses the "prefs:root=" non-public URL scheme, which is a private entity. The use of non-public APIs is not permitted on the App Store because it can lead to a poor user experience should these APIs change.

I have seen several issues opened on this subject for the native iOS app but not Cordova or Ionic.  Is there a way to resolve this in Cordova?   Ironically, the build that got reject has only a minor change that shows a number with 3 decimals instead of 2. Everything else is the same.  Yet, it got rejected.

Below is the list of all the plugins I have:

card.io.cordova.mobilesdk 2.1.0 "CardIO"
cordova-android-support-gradle-release 0.0.2 "cordova-android-support-gradle-release"
cordova-plugin-actionsheet 2.3.3 "ActionSheet"
cordova-plugin-app-event 1.2.1 "Application Events"
cordova-plugin-camera 2.4.1 "Camera"
cordova-plugin-compat 1.2.0 "Compat"
cordova-plugin-datepicker 0.9.3 "DatePicker"
cordova-plugin-device 1.1.6 "Device"
cordova-plugin-dialogs 1.3.3 "Notification"
cordova-plugin-facebook4 1.9.1 "Facebook Connect"
cordova-plugin-file 4.3.3 "File"
cordova-plugin-file-transfer 1.6.3 "File Transfer"
cordova-plugin-google-analytics 1.8.3 "Google Universal Analytics Plugin"
cordova-plugin-googleplus 5.3.1 "Google SignIn"
cordova-plugin-inappbrowser 1.7.1 "InAppBrowser"
cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 1.2.1 "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview"
cordova-plugin-splashscreen 4.0.3 "Splashscreen"
cordova-plugin-statusbar 2.2.4-dev "StatusBar"
cordova-plugin-touchid 0.4.0 "Touch ID"
cordova-plugin-vibration 2.1.5 "Vibration"
cordova-plugin-whitelist 1.3.2 "Whitelist"
cordova-plugin-x-socialsharing 5.4.1 "SocialSharing"
cordova.plugins.diagnostic 3.7.1 "Diagnostic"
de.appplant.cordova.plugin.local-notification 0.8.5 "LocalNotification"
es6-promise-plugin 4.2.2 "Promise"
ionic-plugin-keyboard 2.2.1 "Keyboard"
phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner 7.0.0 "BarcodeScanner"

Comment: You will need to search through the plugins you are using in order to identify which one is using the `prefs:` url.  You should be able to use `find` and `grep` in a terminal to do it.

Comment: @Paulw11 - I used grep -r -i 'prefs' ./*  under the plugins directory and had found two references. Updated my cordova plugins and don't see them anymore.  Hopefully this will do it.

Answer (score 0):

As @Paulw11 suggested -

1. Run  grep -r -i 'prefs' ./* under the plugins directory
2. Find references to the prefs
3. Update the plugins.
4. No code changes required.
5. Rebuild it and submit the archive.

Note:  You may have to update all the plugins.  I would highly recommend making a backup of all the plugins before updating them.